# Mismatched Tag ExpatError when using office365 package in Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, office365

I get a mismatched tag error when running a simple Python script. I am interested in accessing my company's Sharepoint site, and downloading some files automatically.

I am using the Office365-REST-Python-Client. I am compling the code first in Jupyter Notebook, I'm not sure if that would make a difference. I am failing before I even begin. Here is my code:

I am using code taken from https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client#Working-with-OneDrive-API

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
site_url = "https://{your-tenant-prefix}.sharepoint.com"
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential("{username}", "{password}"))
web = ctx.web.get().execute_query()
print("Web title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))
```

I have tried several variations on this. Im pretty sure my credentials are working, and I got the access token to work (that was my first error, but I fixed that). However, the error message is still the same.

```
ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 25, column 71
```

I am guessing it has something to do with parsing xml vs html, but I am fairly lost. I would appreciate any insight.